# Why does targeting a child component work in Vue2 without using the `::v-deep` selector?

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, css-selectors

I have a project in Vue 2.x and I am wondering why targeting a child component's class works *without* using the `/deep/`, `::v-deep` or `>>>` selectors.

I am using these within the project:

```
"node-sass": "5.0.0",
"sass": "1.32.12",
"sass-loader": "10.1.1",
```

Additionally I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-galois-s9rpc?file=/src/App.vue) to demonstrate the issue in real time.

If I am in a parent component I am able to target a child component even within **scoped** styles like this:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .parent-component {
    .child-component {
      /* I set the child components background color even though I don't use a `deep` selector */
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
</style>
```

And in the child component I have:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .child-component {
    /* I'm overwritten by the parent component */
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

From my understanding of how scoped styles work, this should not actually work without me doing something like this in the parent:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .parent-component {
    ::v-deep .child-component {
      background-color: blue;
    }
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can affect only root element of child component without using `::v-deep`. If you write like this, the style will not be applied.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="child-comp">
      How in the world am I styled without /deep/ or ::v-deep or >>>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Interesting, I must have missed that in the docs. Thanks! 

For any future readers who want to see a _working_ fiddle it's here: https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-tdd-1y914?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: are you saying that targeting a root element of the child component wont work with /deep/ operator in scoped style in parent component?